# Swift 4 UITableView Cell height not working

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift4

I'm trying to set the height on Xcode9, except it doesn't seem to work. I can get away with a fixed size of 76. I have an Image in there which I want to have 10 padding with a height of 56.

What I've tried:
1. Setting it in the Size Inspector
2. Through coding, but it's not working

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 76
    getArticles() // returns json data
}
```

And the tableView

```
    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ArticleCell") as? ArticleCell else { return UITableViewCell() }

    cell.titleLabel.text = articles[indexPath.row].title

    if let imageURL = URL(string: articles[indexPath.row].image) {
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            let data = try? Data(contentsOf: imageURL)
            if let data = data {
                let image = UIImage(data: data)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    cell.imgView.image = image
                }
            }
        }
    }

    cell.contentView.setNeedsLayout()
    cell.contentView.layoutIfNeeded()

    return (cell)
}
```

Nothing seems to work, and it stays at the same height. I have tried it with and without contraints.

What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT**
I have changed from Prototype cell to Xib. Now I have it working, except of I get constraints errors.

[image: The constraints setup]
This is the only way it works. If I remove the bottom margins, it goes back to the smaller size again. Same if I remove the image height.

```
    2017-09-25 19:26:37.842902+0200 Proj010916-NL_nl[56361:915542] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60c000093c90 UIImageView:0x7fec2800cd60.height == 56   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60c000093ce0 UIImageView:0x7fec2800cd60.top == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fec2800aa70.topMargin + 10   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60c000093d80 UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fec2800aa70.bottomMargin == UIImageView:0x7fec2800cd60.bottom + 10   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x604000097160 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fec2800aa70.height == 92   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60c000093c90 UIImageView:0x7fec2800cd60.height == 56   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Next task is to redo the segue since it's now a vc and not a cell inside anymore.

Comment: Your code is correct. You should add some constraints to the `ArticleCell` xib file, add them and make sure you have constraints connecting the content to the top and bottom of the superview.  Then if it still isn't working, post your constraints on this question so we can help you fix them.

Comment: Updated constraints info.

Comment: Read the logs, you'll know that iOS breaks your constraint, the constant height 56. It conflicts with another constraint/s. Think about it.

Comment: That was stupid. Sorry. Been a long day. I've removed the height, added the aspect constraint and put it to @999. This seems to work now.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried implementing the heightForRowAtIndexPath delegate method?

```
 override open func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 76.0
 }
```

That way you can set different heights for each indexPath in the UITableView.

Comment: I think he's trying to implement auto resizing tableViewCell. Constraints is the key to that.